# Limitations of Parquet file format

Tags: bigdata, limit, parquet

Is there any limitations in parquet file format for the following?

1. No. of columns.
2. No. of partitions and No. of sub partitions inside
   each partition.
3. Size of each column.

Comment: i don't find any limitations in the official documentation. Probably the limitations stands in the system when supports the Parquet format